# I want to generate(or count) all possible binary matrix that satisfy certain Condition

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I want to generate(or count) all possible binary matrix that satisfy below Condition.
let A be arbitrary binary matrix 4*4

> ```
> A=   [0 0 1 1]
>      [0 0 1 1]
>      [1 1 0 0]
>      [1 1 0 0] 
>
> [sum(row1) sum(r2) sum(r3) sum(r4) sum(column1) sum(c2) sum(c3) sum(c4)]
>
> condition: [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
> 1)how many matrix satisfy above condition?
> 2)how can i generate them?
>
> answer 1 is:90 
> but i want a formula or algorithm
> because i want to use it for 1024*1024 or upper and every arbitrary condition
> vector.
> ```

Comment: These are known as binary contingency tables with specified margins (i.e. the row and column sums).